# NodeJS, unrestricted file upload, RCE

Tags: web-application, xss, file-upload, node.js, remote-code-execution

I'm testing on application which runs on **NodeJS**, and discovered unrestriced file upload vulnerability, path traversal is not possible.

Uploaded file is visitable, I can upload **.html** to perform XSS attack, however I want something more. I'm looking to perform **Remote Code Execution (RCE)**, I have tried uploading all kinds of extensions however none had success executing code.

Is there possibility to execute code similary to uploading **.php on php powered app**?

In my own research I have not discovered any writeup covering this up.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as [your previous one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/252166/ruby-on-rails-unrestricted-file-upload-rce), only now with nodejs instead of RoR? Do we get this kind of question now with every framework out there? Note that even with .php files there is no universal way to execute it, i.e. not every arbitrary file upload will automatically result in a vulnerability with PHP.

Comment: What is problem of asking? RoR and node.js are not same if u didn't know...so thats why two different questions.
In my testing when I have discovered unrestricted file upload(on php powered apps) and was able to upload .php it in 99% targets resulted in code execution and I have tested a lot...As said i'm not familiar with node.js or RoR apps, so any help is useful :)

Comment: You are right that there is no problem with asking by itself. Your question though seems to assume that there might be a generic vulnerability based on the idea that there is such vulnerability for PHP - even though there isn't one for PHP either. As I already said in a comment on your last question: unrestricted file upload is not a problem for RCE if the path is not accessible/executable by the webserver or if you don't manage the web application to somehow load and execute the file (i.e. LFI). But you don't show that any of these preconditions are there.

Comment: "I have not found a problem on my target. How can I find one?" That's not really answerable and depends on the target. You appear to be asking for an inherent, unaddressed flaw in the framework(s).

Comment: @schroeder What? Unrestriced file upload does look like not a problem to you? This software uses CMS and I have Stored XSS on over 900 targets already via this vulnerability.
I asked if its possible to chain to RCE via SSTI or extension i'm unaware of. What is not answerable here? Question is very clear.

Comment: "I'm looking to perform Remote Code Execution (RCE), I have tried uploading all kinds of extensions however none had success executing code." -- "I have not found a problem on my target. How can I find one?"

Comment: And no, unrestricted file upload is not an inherent problem. Google Drive allows unrestricted uploads. So does S3, and, and and ...

Comment: The question is clear. But please review the close reason. The issue is not clarity.

Comment: @schroeder can you please explain what is wrong with that question? As said on both my questions for Node.js and RoR that i'm not familiar with their code structure and what extensions they use, maybe I missed something simple so thats why asked here. You clearly don't have answer so why reply? are you farming reputation or something?
Just beacuse I have not found solution to executing code does not mean it's not a problem and somebody else does not know answer to it aka why I posted question here.

Comment: I have explained. And resorting to personal attacks is not necessary. Chiil out. You have asked "help me hack this" without any specific question. We have a canned closed response for these types of questions. Without a specific question, it's too open-ended.

Comment: "Just beacuse I have not found solution to executing code does not mean it's not a problem" -- you are absolutely correct. This question being closed does not mean that I do not believe there could possibly be a vulnerability. The issue is with the question. You do not know if there is a vulnerability. So, asking how to exploit an unknown vulnerability is not answerable.